# UIViewControllerRepresentable runtime error: Nib is loaded but view outlet wasn't set. Why?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm toying with SwiftUI's access to a UIViewController via the UIViewControllerRepresentable protocol; using a Nib vs instantiating the class manually.

Most of the demo sample I've seen has the ViewController instantiated in code; as shown below:

```
struct RicViewVC: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    // Parameters ----------------------------
    // let url: URL
    @Binding var showingVC: Bool
    // ---------------------------------------

    // 1)
    func makeUIViewController(context _: Context) -> RicViewController {
        let viewController = RicViewController()
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RicView", owner: viewController, options: nil)
        return viewController
    }

    // 2)
    func updateUIViewController(_: RicViewController, context _: Context) {}

    // 3
    func makeCoordinator() -> RicViewVC.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(showing: $showingVC)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        @Binding var showingCoord: Bool

        init(showing: Binding<Bool>) {
            _showingCoord = showing
        }
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work when the UIViewController is linked with and IB:

> Hello from RicViewController 2020-02-23 10:53:55.893551-0800
>
> SafariRepresentable[9792:151550] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the
>   "RicView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

This is where I'm confused. 
How do I link the IB's instantiated XIB into #1 (see above code): makeUIViewController()?

What's the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If your `RicViewController` is XIB owner, then try the following

```
let viewController = RicViewController(nibName: "_nib_name_here", bundle: nil) // if bundle not main the specify also bundle
return viewController
```

Comment: I made the change per your suggestion.   But I'm still getting the error.
How do I set the view outlet?  ... being the view is already integral to the VC and should already be accessible.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee, all outlets have to link automatically on owner loaded. Please try updated variant.

Comment: I tried that per ref to same problem.   I got an exception that the view was reference twice (2x).  But then I change the ref of File's Owner view --> view, to File's Owner's view --> ViewController and it works.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee, that is the first line in my answer, as I don't see your xib, controller have to be xib owner.

Comment: ...my comment was in error but 5 minutes passed and I couldn't edit it.   It turns out I need to link my UILabel (view); not the actual UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

There was a solo UILabel in my UIViewController's View that wasn't referenced.
After a trial/error and ref a similar problem on StackOverFlow, I found that I had to:

1) Set the File's Owner to 'RicViewController'; and 
2) Set a link between the VC-View's one UILabel to the File's Owner Connection Inspector's 'view'.

[image]
[image]